# Use v-on and .sync modifier in v-bind

Tags: vue.js

I fail to find a way to use `v-on` and `.sync` modifier together with `v-bind`.

When using vuetify v-text-field, the following works:

```html
<v-text-field v-model='value' @input="doSomething"><v-text-field>
```

However, the following do not work. The console log is not event triggered.
What am I doing wrong?

```html
<v-text-field v-bind='setInput'><v-text-field>
```

with:

```js
data () {
  return {
    value: 0
  }
},
methods: {
  setInput () {
    return {
      value: this.value,
      on: { 
       input: event => {
         console.log(event)
         this.value = event
       } 
      } 
   }
  }
}
```

I have many complex form to design and want to simplify form declaration using v-bind.
Note that Vuetify is a project constrain.
Also, how would you achieve `v-model.sync' in that context ?

Thanks

Comment: This happens because we can not bind an event listener, we have to use a `v-on` directive for that. You can still create two separate methods to acheive the same.

Comment: v-bind is only for flowing data from data source to control and not from control to data source

Comment: Ok thanks both for your answer.